# Flexbox: one element is missing

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three elements in a row. I need to divide them in the following way:

```
flex: 0 0 20%;
max-width: 20%;
min-width: 20%;
```

But the result looks like this: [image]

What exactly I want to get is that the green bar contains the sixth element. How to achieve that?

Comment: 100% divided by 6 isnt 20% ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the width to 20% that means you can have exactly 5 elements in a row. If you want the next item to wrap on a new row you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap`

If you want the elements to always span 100% regardless of how many there are then simply don't specify any widht.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
}

.flex--element {
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

<div class="flex--element">
 Element
</div>

<div class="flex--element">
 Element
</div>

<div class="flex--element">
 Element
</div>

<div class="flex--element">
 Element
</div>

</div>
```